# tsconfig paths are not working in ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, ts-node

I know this question has been asked a lot of times. But none of the solutions seems to work for me.

I have setup a project installing typescript and ts-node to run the project in dev.

The project structure is as follows

```
.
├── src
│   ├── utils
│   │   └── logger.ts
│   ├── custom
│   │   └── services
|   |       └── func.service.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Below is my `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "removeComments": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "paths": {
            "@utils/*": [
                "utils/*"
            ],
            "@custom/*": [
                "custom/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I am importing the utils/logger in the src/index.ts file as `import { Log } from '@utils/logger'`

so when I run the below command

```bash
$ yarn dev
```

(which is configured to run `ts-node src/index`)

I am getting the below error

```
$ ts-node src/index
Error: Cannot find module '@utils/logger'
...
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
...
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Went through different answers in the site, but none of them worked.

---

Edit: The intellisense in vscode works fine and detects the paths correctly

Comment: "_Went through different answers in the site, but none of them worked._" links please.